# Add a sub-column to multi-level dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

My dataframe looks like

```
    First    Second
    A   B    A   B 
1   50  60   70  100
2   20  5    10  30
3   35  45   60  50
```

I want to add a new sub-column in each top-level column using `.diff()`, so it would look like (in this case, taking the differences of the `B` column)

```
       First          Second
    A   B   Diff     A    B    Diff
1   50  60  NaN      70   100  NaN
2   20  5   -55      10   30   -70
3   35  45  40       60   50   20
```

I think that there should be a clean way to do this without for loops and other inefficient native python operations but I'm not sure how.

**Source dataframe :**

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    ('First', 'A'): [50, 20, 35],
    ('First', 'B'): [60, 5, 45],
    ('Second', 'A'): [70, 10, 60],
    ('Second', 'B'): [100, 30, 50]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```py
df[[(c, "Diff") for c in df.columns.unique(0)]] = df.loc[:, (slice(None), "B")].diff()
df = df.sort_index(axis=1)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  First           Second           
      A   B  Diff      A    B  Diff
1    50  60   NaN     70  100   NaN
2    20   5 -55.0     10   30 -70.0
3    35  45  40.0     60   50  20.0
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

Another approach

If you don't want to overwrite the original or list comprehension,

you can use `concat`.

```
tmp = df.loc[:, (slice(None), "B")].diff().rename({'B': 'Diff'}, axis=1, level=1)
out = pd.concat([df, tmp], axis=1).sort_index(level=0, axis=1)
```

out:

```
    First           Second
    A   B   Diff    A   B   Diff
0   50  60  NaN     70  100 NaN
1   20  5   -55.0   10  30  -70.0
2   35  45  40.0    60  50  20.0
```

---

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {('First', 'A'): [50, 20, 35],
 ('First', 'B'): [60, 5, 45],
 ('Second', 'A'): [70, 10, 60],
 ('Second', 'B'): [100, 30, 50]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Method 1 :`

```py
r = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(lambda df: df.xs('B', level=1, axis=1).diff())
r = pd.concat([df, r.rename(columns={'First': 'Diff', 'Second': 'Diff'}, level=1)], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)

print(r)
```

```
  First           Second           
      A   B  Diff      A    B  Diff
0    50  60   NaN     70  100   NaN
1    20   5 -55.0     10   30 -70.0
2    35  45  40.0     60   50  20.0
```

`Method 2 :`

```py
for label in df.columns.get_level_values(0).unique():
    df[(label, 'diff')] = df[(label, 'B')].diff()
    
df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
```

`Timings :`

```
# Laurent B. (2) : 0.0017528533935546875
# Panda Kim : 0.0029146671295166016
# Laurent B. (1) : 0.005835294723510742
# Andrej Kesely : 0.013051748275756836
```